# How to send a callback from firebase 'addOnCompleteListener'? (Clean Architecture) Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, clean-architecture

For my project, I am using Clean Architecture. I have a presentation layer, domain layer and data layer. In the data layer I have the firebase operations. When I want to register a user in firebase it works. The only problem is that I want to have a callback so that I can display a progress bar in the UI. Now I know that it usually takes a while before the 'addOnCompleteListener' of 'createUserWithEmalAndPassword' is ready. Is there a way to send a callback to the presentation layer without breaking the rules of clean architecture?

Below my code:

ViewModel (Presentation layer):

```
fun createUser(email: String, password: String) {
      createUser.invoke(email, password)
}
```

UseCase (Domaian layer):

```
class CreateUser @Inject constructor(
    private val authenticationDomainRepository: AuthenticationDomainRepository
) {
     operator fun invoke(email: String, password: String) {
        authenticationDomainRepository.createUser(email, password)
    }
}
```

AuthenticationDomainRepository (Domain layer):

```
interface AuthenticationDomainRepository {
    fun createUser(email: String, password: String)
}
```

AuthenticationRepository (Data layer):

```
class AuthenticationRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager
) : AuthenticationDomainRepository {
    override fun createUser(email: String, password: String) {
        authenticationManager.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }
}
```

AuthenticationManager (Data layer):

```
class AuthenticationManager @Inject constructor() {

    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth by lazy {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }

    fun createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String) {
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }
}
```

Comment: `Is there a way to send a callback to the presentation layer without breaking the rules of clean architecture?` what have you tried ? what isn't working ? you already know of callbacks, so what isn't working

Comment: @a_local_nobody I tried to return a boolean to see if the registration is successful. It is always false because it take some time for de addOnCompleteListener to finish. So I though maybe I can use callback but I don't know how to implement it. Because I don't want that the presentation Layer knows about the data layer and vice versa.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value/57330767#57330767

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) as well as this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) will help, when it comes to authentication and clean architecture.

Comment: One option would be to post the result to [live data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70178210/9473786) that the view layer observes. Or you can pass in callbacks from the view layer like `showProg` and `hideProg` that the lower layers can call at the appropriate times